# How do I place a configurable meme at the bottom of the index page in ghost?

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost

I'm working on a blog for a friend of mine who wants to put a meme picture at the bottom of the index page.

So the simplest way is to edit the template and reference it from there.
The problem is, it's not user friendly to keep editing and uploading a new template.

So I had this idea that I could create a static page and place it on that page and reference it from the template.  But I see that when you upload an image to ghost.io it generates a name based on the date path.  That's not going to work for a fixed URL in the template.

Another option might be to use the tags.  As tags allows you to put a picture and has a URL.  But I tried that it also has similar problems.

How can I make this work nicely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reference image URL in your theme. Reference page slug and load its content, which would be just an image.

Example with Ghost Handlebars API:

```
{{!-- If a static page "meme" exists - its content will be loaded here --}}

{{#get "posts" slug="meme" }}
    {{#foreach posts}}
        <div>
            {{content}}
        </div>
    {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

Comment: How would I add that to the casper theme?  I tried addit it to index.hbs after {{> "loop"}} but it throws out fatal errors when I tried to load the theme. e.g. Replace the {{cover}} helper with {{cover_image}} and Replace the {{image}} helper with {{img_url feature_image}} or {{img_url profile_image}} etc.  There is a whole page full of these.

Comment: It looks that you are trying to load old theme (for 0.11.X) to a new Ghost 1.X.X - and it is not compatible, because there were breaking changes for themes. http://themes.ghost.org/docs/migrate-to-ghost-1-0-0#section-fix-any-fatal-errors.

Comment: Are you saying http://ghost.io is not running 1.x.x and is out of date?

Comment: Ghost.io is running 1.x.x. Your Casper based theme source files are out of date. You have build your theme based on Casper 1 but there is a new Casper 2.0 for Ghost 1.x.x.

Comment: Actually the version number displayed for the theme is 2.0.2.

Comment: There is no {{> "loop"}} in Casper 2.0.2 index.hbs. So, please check again your files - something is wrong here apparently. Anyway I'm, sure that errors you see are version related and fixing it would be my next step - it's not that hard actually, just some variables names changed.